# Same function different MD5 hash results

Tags: javascript, md5

I am trying to calculate the hash of a string. And I found that the result changes depending on the method I use.

In this webpage https://codebeautify.org/md5-hash-generator.

If I use the form writing the string in the text field:

```
16120&{"number":"4545","params":"{\"locale\":\"en_EN\"}"}
```

I get 26528d6e0e802d5569e2e03fde0a825c. However if I do

```
CryptoJS.MD5('16120&{"number":"4545","params":"{\"locale\":\"en_EN\"}"}').toString();
```

the result is fe31f378efcc4ae4de71e70278991741.

If I use a simple string like 1234 I get the same result but using the one above I don't so I guess the problem is escaped bars or something but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The Backslashes for escaping the string are only ok in-code because they will not be part of the resulting string. See [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp) -> chapter "Escape Character".
Try executing `console.log('\"')` to understand this, it results in logging only a single doublequote (`"`).

So if you remove these escape characters and insert the string in the input (where escaping is neither needed nor supported), the hash will be equal.

Comment: Exactly this is the issue, see my edit, too. The escape-characters are only allowed in-code, where the compiler removes them later on. On the web page, this isn't the case so you need to remove them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In your JS code, JS is escaping the quotes. The website is not escaping. So you are hashing different things, hence different hash results.

Answer (score 0):

The backslashes in the second case need to be doubled up. Once for JavaScript and once for JSON.

```
CryptoJS.MD5('16120&{"number":"4545","params":"{\\"locale\\":\\"en_EN\\"}"}').toString();
```